# Can restaurants call cops on customers who leave fake "Jesus money" as tip?

Tags: currency

I've been reading that in the US there's a thing where certain kinds of people leave fake bills with just a corner showing just the dollar amount and the rest hidden under a napkin or peeking out of the check holder, but upon closer inspection turns out to be not real money. Such fake bills contain christian-adjacent texts which read things to the effect of "Jesus's love is more important than money".

I don't think anyone can tell for sure if any such person who leaves these fake bills does it as a way to propagate their religious beliefs, or to be a cheapskate with an "excuse", but the bottom line is they're leaving fake bills instead of real bills, and it's not cool to the servers.

Some say that the Secret Service will only investigate if the bills appear to be at least not obviously fake in full view, but the way these bills are used, only the real-looking portion is left in the open until the server comes over to collect them.

Is such use of "Jesus money" illegal? Can servers (or managers) of restaurants call the police on the customers for doing that?

Comment: I'm not based in the US or Europe, so I suppose the question is multinational, if that's allowed.

Comment: Well it's still *theft* if the person took food without paying for it which is definitely illegal. The information you seem to have found is probably just saying that the government won't investigate it for counterfeitting because only a part of it is designed to look like a bill, not the entire thing. It's not a counterfeit bill in the eyes of the law. Theft is the responsibility of local law enforcement to investigate.

Comment: The cases I see mentioned which get conflicting opinions about specifically say that the main part of the bill is paid in real money, but the tip (which is arguably optional and may or may not be considered theft) is left in such fake bills.

Comment: Then there's nothing for anyone to do. Tips are not required, and the government has stated that it's not counterfeitting. Someone leaving a religious note is no different than not leaving anything at all in the eyes of the law.

Comment: @user1306322 is the "Jesus money" paying for the restraunt meal or just the tip portion of the restraunt meal. The title looks like you're referring to the tip where the content is more general.

Comment: The police generally do not like to be bothered with things that are not actually crimes. Leaving a worthless tip is not a crime. Calling the police would be counter-productive at best.

Answer (score 4):

If only the tip is left in such "fake" money, it would not be theft as there is no legal obligation to leave a tip at all (except in those establishments that add a tip or "service charge' to the bill.) If the "money" is not an attempt to imitate real cash, it wouldn't be counterfeiting (leaving monopoly money for example would not be counterfeiting). The server would be understandably angry. The restaurant might refuse to seat the people who left the "fake" another time, if the servers identified them to the manager, but nothing would require them to do so.

This is all on a US basis, I have no idea if tips might be legally required in other countries.

Answer (score 2):

There is no legal obligation to pay tips — pretty much like no laws oblige people to be civilized and nice.

No law breaking — no basis for calling cops.

Answer (score 0):

Not paying for a meal, by leaving fake money rather than real money, is theft and a crime. Therefore, it is appropriate to report the crime to police just at it would be if the patrons had "dined and dashed" without even leaving fake money.

Realistically, in the absence of security video, it may be virtually impossible to apprehend the perpetrators based on the report.  But, a police report would substantiate the incident if it happened again, so, if the perpetrators were identified by waitstaff before they fled and were either detained in a citizens arrest or discouraged from leaving in a manner that allowed police to arrive an apprehend them, they could be arrested later.

This would not be counterfeiting in most countries since it isn't really trying to make coins or currency that pass as the real thing, just plain old theft.

Comment: Right, but what about when only the tip is left in fake bills, but the meal portion of the check is paid properly?

Comment: Then, it is merely rude and the restaurant should ban them from the restaurant going forward for their gall.

Comment: Are tips not protected by law from being paid in fake bills like that? Not in the US, Canada, UK, European countries or anywhere else where tips are a thing?

Comment: The way to conceptualize it is that tips weren't paid at all, not that tips were paid but that the bills were fake. Leaving fake bills that are obviously fake like that is really the same as leaving nothing at all but a rude message.

Comment: Tips are, by definition, optional. Always.

Comment: @Upnorth But certainly, paying a tip in truly counterfeit money would be a crime even though it would not be theft.

Comment: @ohwilleke We agree that's not what happened here. There was no crime, thus it would be pointless to summon the police.

Comment: On the other hand, from other websites I got the understanding that this is done by people who claim to be Christians, ostensibly to spread the message of Jesus. I'd say they are not Christians, quite the opposite.

Comment: I would agree were they tipping, say, their hairstylist. But in the US wait staff are paid below minimum wage specifically because management expects the customer to pay the rest of the waiter's wages through "tipping." Does this effect your analysis?

Comment: @RubelliteFae No.

Answer (score -3):

As was explained in other answers, there will be no prosecution if they paid tips with fake money. But you don't know that, do you? You are not a lawyer who knows the details of what constitutes fake money and what doesn't?

So I'd say you treat that like you would treat fake money: You hold them and call the police. There's even a chance that you would get a police officer who is a devout Christian and gives them a free lecture about what is and what isn't Christian behaviour.

@Swizzler. You say they can't do anything. I say they can call the cops - and if you read the headline of the question, that was "can I call the cops". If something happens that you believe is a crime, you can call the cops. Whether you are right or not.

Comment: What a bad answer. If the bills are obviously fake and left as extra, not to pay any open bills, you can't do anything. Same if they pay everything and then pass you monopoly-money with a smirk and tell you "for your efford". Its rude at best but not illegal.

Comment: "But you don't know that, do you?" - That's why they are asking! You're wasting the police's time if you call them for this.

Comment: @DM whether it is truly wasting police time depends on the jurisdiction and whether they have something better to do.  In some small towns, they might appreciate the distraction.

Comment: @Swizzler I think the point is that your average restaurant manager, in the moment, doesn't necessarily know whether the money might violate some law, and would therefore be justified in calling the police.

Comment: @phoog It's true that in some small towns the police might have time for frivolous calls. But this guy seems to think that it's a good idea to call the police because the police might try to actually track the rude person down (I'll assume "hold them" refers to the fake bills and not the people, or we have *other* problems) and give them some sort of lecture on Christianity. That's problematic for several reasons.

Comment: @gnasher729 regarding your edit...you can always call the cops. Even to ask them what they recommend you to eat for lunch. Or, to take an example from school: "can I go to the toilet?" "I don't know, can you?". Apply common sense whenever possible.

Comment: Seriously. I don't how you can get to 9,000 reputation points without figuring out how to read beyond the literal phrasing of a question and answer the real question instead.

Comment: Yea I can do anything I want, but obviously (or I guess not obviously enough?) I meant to ask whether it would be a reasonable reaction, or if it would be wise, etc. Maybe if you think this is too badly phrased, edit the question.